# Minimal code to cast MultiSelectList.SelectedValues to String[]

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, casting

Is this all necessary to cast to a string[]

```
string[] waterfrontoptions = Model.WaterfrontOptions.
    SelectedValues.Cast<String>() == null 
    ? Model.WaterfrontOptions.SelectedValues.Cast<String>().ToArray() : null;
```

all I want to do is a .Contains on the values in the .SelectedValues property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, too much. `SelectedValues.Cast<String>()` is never null. If `SelectedValues` is null `Cast` will throw an exception. You can do:

```
Model.WaterfrontOptions.SelectedValues.OfType<string>().Contains(xxxx);
```

This *filters* the strings in `SelectedValues`. If you want to *convert* to string:

```
Model.WaterfrontOptions.SelectedValues.Select(v => v.ToString()).Contains(xxxx);
```

I assume that neither `WaterfrontOptions` nor `SelectedValues` can be `null` (as your original code has `SelectedValues.Cast`).